# If $\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ is integrable for every functional $φ$, is there an $x$ with $\langle x,\varphi\rangle=\int\langle f,φ\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space, $E$ be a normed space and $f:\Omega\to E$ be strongly$^1$ $\mathcal A$-measurable with $$\langle f,\varphi\rangle\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'.$$

> Are we able to show that $$\int\langle f,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu=\langle x,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'\tag1$$ for some $x\in E$? If not, what are sufficient conditions to ensure that?

If $f$ has finite range, the claim is obviously true. If not, there are $\mathcal A$-measurable $f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with finite range for $n\in\mathbb N$ satisfying $\left\|f_n\right\|_E\le\left\|f\right\|_E$ and $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. So, there are $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ with $$\int\langle f_n,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu=\langle x_n,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'\text{ and }n\in\mathbb N\tag2.$$ Using Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem, it's now easy to see that $$\langle x_n,\varphi\rangle\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int\langle f,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu\tag3\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E',$$ which at least implies that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is weakly Cauchy.

> However, we know that a weak Cauchy sequence doesn't need to weakly converge. So, maybe the problem I'm asking here is a particular instance of the fact that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is *any* weakl Cauchy sequence, then $$L\varphi:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,\varphi\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }\varphi\in E'$$ is a well-defined linear functional (since the field over which $E$ is a vector space is complete), but $L$ is not necessarily of the form $$L\varphi=\langle x,\varphi\rangle\tag4$$ for some $x\in E$.
>
> Maybe all of this boils down to the properties of the canonical embedding $$\iota:E\to E''\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto\left(E'\ni\varphi\mapsto\langle x,\varphi\rangle\right).$$

In any case, I would really appreciate if someone could show under which conditions we are able to prove the desired result; but I'm also interested in results related to the general case for the functional $L$.

### **EDIT**

As [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra) pointed out in the comments, it seems like the question boils down to find conditions under which a Dunford integrable function is even Pettis integrable. Let me fix the terminology:

> $f:\Omega\to E$ to is called **Dunford $\mu$-integrable** if $\langle f,\varphi\rangle\mathcal L^1(\mu)$. In that case, $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu:E'\to\mathbb K\;,\;\;\;\varphi\mapsto\int\langle f,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu\tag5$$ is a bounded linear functional on $E'$, i.e. $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\in E''.\tag6$$ Now $f$ is called **Pettis $\mu$-integrable** if $f$ is Dunford $\mu$-integrable and $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\in\iota E.\tag7$$

*First approach for a positive result*: I've often seen the assertion that the desired claim is true when $\Omega=[a,b]$ for some $a<b$, $\mathcal A=\mathcal B([a,b])$, $\mu$ is the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ to $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous. The crucial argument is that $[a,b]$ is compact, hence $f$ is even uniformly continuous, which allows us to find $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ such that $$\langle x_n,\varphi\rangle\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int\langle f,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu\tag8$$ uniformly with respect to $\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le1$. By Lemma 1 below, this is enough to conclude, but I'm quite sure that this result holds in way more generality.

> **Lemma 1**: In general, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ is norm convergent if and only if $$\sup_{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le1}\left|\langle x_m-x_n,\varphi\rangle\right|\xrightarrow{m,\:n\to\infty}0.$$

*Second approach for a positive result*: Let me continue with the setting I've described at the beginning of this post, i.e. the situation where $f$ is strongly $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Most probably I'm missing something, but if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are as in $(2)$ and $(3)$, then we should have \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sup_{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le1}\left|\langle x_m-x_n,\varphi\rangle\right|&=\sup_{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{E'}\le1}\left|\int\langle f_m-f_n,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu\right|\\&\le\int\left\|f_m-f_n\right\|_E\:{\rm d}\mu\xrightarrow{m,\:n\:\to\:\infty}0\end{split}\tag9.\end{equation} So, by Lemma 1, we should be able to conclude. Am I missing something?

If not and this is correct, is this somehow a generalization of what I've described in the "first approach"? Therein $f$ is continuous (hence $\mathcal A$-measurable) and, since $[a,b]$ is separable, $f([a,b])$ is separable. So, $f$ is strongly $\mathcal A$-measurable. Maybe that's the crucial point.

---

$^1$ i.e. $f$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and $f(\Omega)$ is separable. The crucial point is that a function $f:\Omega\to E$ is strongly $\mathcal A$ if and only if there are $\mathcal A$-measurable $f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with finite range for $n\in\mathbb N$ satisfying $\left\|f_n\right\|_E\le\left\|f\right\|_E$ and $\left\|f_n-f\right\|_E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$.

Comment: Are you asking if a Dunford integrable function is Pettis integrable?

Comment: In general (even assuming completeness) you get an element of $E^{**}$. Reflexivity is needed for an affirmative answer. Ref. Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: The counterexample in Uhl is $f:[0,1]\rightarrow c_0$, $$f(t)=(\chi_{(0,1]}(t), 2\chi_{(0,1/2]}(t), \cdots,n\chi_{(0,1/n]}(t),\cdots),$$ for $t\in[0,1]$. (It is represented by $(1,1,\cdots)$).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for the buzzwords. It seems like my actual question is which conditions are sufficient to obtain Pettis integrability from Dunford integrability.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please take note of my edit.

Comment: I think one is that the space does not contain $c_0$. This is in Uhl's book.

Comment: I just checked, Diestel and Uhl prove this for finite measure spaces, $f$ $\mu$-measurable, and $X$ Banach.

Comment: @DavidMitra I'll take a look into Diestel and Uhl, but what do you think about what I wrote in the "second approach" section? If I'm not missing something, this should yield the claim.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: In order to pass to the limit in (9), you need the additional assumption $\int \|f\|_E \mathrm d \mu < \infty$, i.e. that $f$ is Bochner integrable.

Comment: @gerw Yes, you're right. But I guess that's the actual crucial point of the "first approach". The continuity on the compact set $[a,b]$ ensures Bochner integrability; and the claim is obviously true for Bochner integrable $f$.

Comment: Remark: I think the usual definition for "Pettis integrable" is not that $\int_\Omega f\,d\mu \in \iota E$, but that $\int_T f\,d\mu \in \iota E$ for all $T \in \mathcal A$.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you have an example in mind where those conditions are not equivalent?

Comment: @0xbadf00d ... example with $\Omega = [-1,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.  Let $f$ be Dunford integrable on $[0,1]$ with $\int_{[0,1]} f\,d\mu \notin \iota E$, and let $f(x) = -f(-x)$ on $[-1,0)$.  Then $\int_{[-1,1]} f\;d\,\mu = 0 \in \iota E$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for the example. In that case, we know that for all $A\in\mathcal A$, there is a $x_A\in E$ with $\langle x_A,\varphi\rangle=\int_A\langle f,\varphi\rangle\:{\rm d}\mu$ for all $\varphi\in E'$. Is there some relation between the $x_A$? In particular, can $x_A$ be computed from $x_E$?

Comment: The map $A \mapsto x_A$ is a (vector-valued) measure.  In general, we cannot compute a measure $\mu$ knowing only $\mu(\Omega)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Right. Thank you, once again. If $f$ is Pettis integrable, does $\left\|f\right\|$ need to be measurable? Maybe using a measurable selection theorem? (I know that any weakly measurable function with separable range is strongly measurable)